# Android database setting ImageView

Tags: android, database, imageview, setting

I have a database with 5 columns, 1 column which is a TEXT with the name of a drawable that is /res/drawable folder.

```
    private void fillData() {

    mCursor = db2.getAllAchievements();
    startManagingCursor(mCursor);


    String[] from = new String[]{achHelper.ROW_NAME, achHelper.ROW_DESCRIPTION, achHelper.ROW_POINTS, achHelper.ROW_TROPHY};


    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.achTitle, R.id.achDescription, R.id.achPoints, R.id.trophy};

    SimpleCursorAdapter classes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.ach_row, mCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(classes);
}
```

R.id.trophy is a ImageView, how can I set the background image based on the data that is being pulled from achHelper.ROW_TROPHY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simpleCursorAdapter need Strings, so your StringArray "from" must get String objects from the column `achHelper.ROW_TROPHY` when you setup your database it has to look like this:

```
 private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " here your other colums
                                            + ROW_TROPHY + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
 db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
```

So when you make your entry into your Database you have to convert the ID of your TropyImage (whitch is Integer) R.drawable.yourTropyImage to a string:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put( your other columns, your other input);
cv.put(ROW_TROPHY, Integer.toString(R.drawable.yourTrophyImage));

return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
```

Your `String[] from, int[] to` and `simpleCursorAdapter` seem to be correct. You just must have the right DataType and ID in the `ROW_TROPY` column.